# gradle dynamic calculate version for publishing

Tags: gradle, version-control

I want to automate release management in the version control system and publishing the related artifacts.

Therefore I use the following build script (simplified version for testing)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

// --- Setup artifactory server repository ---
  artifactory_contextUrl="http://vie2rhp02904"
  artifactory_user="admin"
  artifactory_password="..."
  repositories {
    maven { url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release" }
  }  
// -------------------------------------------

defaultTasks 'doit'

group = 'release-test'

version = "13.7-SNAPSHOT"

// --- Setup publishing parameters ---
  publishing.repositories {
    maven {
      credentials {
        username "${artifactory_user}"
        password "${artifactory_password}"
      }
      if (project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-snapshot-local"
      } else {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/libs-release-local"
      }
    }
  }

  project.publishing.publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
    }
  }
// -------------------------------------------

task createReleaseVersion << {
  println("Version at start: $version")
  // Doing release management, which builds a tagged version without the "-SNAPSHOT" phrase
  version = "13.7.0"
  println("actual version: $version")
}

task doit (dependsOn: ['createReleaseVersion', 'publish'] ) << {
}

publish.mustRunAfter createReleaseVersion
```

Everythings works fine as long as I do not change the **version** property within the execution of a task. (Is done in the createReleaseVersion task)

If I change the version, the JAR file is created with the correct name, but the publishing wants to use the name according to the old version.

How can I publish using the version calculated during the task execution?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `publishing` is configured before your task gets executed.

I'm not sure if its safe to update `publishing` configuration from your task during execution (you can try though). A better solution for this problem would be to use project parameters. For example, you can change `build.gradle` like this:

```
version = "13.7"
if (!project.hasProperty('buildRelease')) {
    version += "-SNAPSHOT";
}
```

If you will simply run your tasks, version would be `13.7-SNAPSHOT`

But if you set project property `buildRelease`, version would be `13.7`

To set project property use `-P` prefix when you run the task, for example:

```
gradle publish -PbuildRelease=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that the reason is because of the order of the execution.
But I am hoping that there is a way around this.
Later configuration editing is not allowed by gradle. (Have already tried it)

Setting the version manually does not bring me further, because the main reason of this task is to calculate the new version automatically.

My woarkaround at the moment is to use a batch file, that calls gradle twice. The first time I update the version property in the gradle.properties file and then I do the rest using the new version.

But I would prefer to do it in one call

Comment: @Horst can you put the code of your task inside my if statement? you can add it to the question so we could see what is happening

Comment: Sorry I do not know, what you mean? One can reproduce my problem by calling "gradle doit" with my build script. It publishes with the wrong (initially set) version